# How to fix CSS Dropdown Design

Tags: html, css

how to fix the css dropdown design for each list. I can't seem to get the design fixed.

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li  class='active'>
<a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Festival</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>


<li id=ListDrop><a href='#'>Tourist Destinations</a>
<ul id=Sites>
  <li><a href='#'>Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Gallery</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Location Map</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>References</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #cssmenu:after,
 #cssmenu > ul:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
 height: 0;
 }
 #cssmenu {
 width: auto;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #47c9af;
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1;
 }
 #cssmenu ul {
 background: #ffffff;
 }
 #cssmenu > ul > li {
 float: left;
 }
 #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
 font-size: 0;
 text-align: center;
 }
 #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 }
 #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
 float: right;
 }
 #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: -4px;
 }
 #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
 z-index: 2;
 padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-decoration: none;

  }
 #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
 #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
 #cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 }
 #cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
   z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
   transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
   transform-origin: bottom;
   }
   #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after,
   #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
   #cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
    background: #47c9af;
   }
```

I wanted to apply the same design on the submenu on the dropdown but I can't seem to fix it or apply the same. Can anyone help me with the code? I'm having problems with the design. Any guide will help thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply same design to submenu links then dont use > in your css.
For example instead of
 `#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after`
 do
 `#cssmenu ul li.active a:after`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the Gallery links to be at the bottom and just styled the same way then as svemirac said you should remove the >

However if you want a proper drop-down menu I recommend a cleaner version of your code following the drop-down menu from W3Schools.

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Here is a jsfiddle that is cleaner.
However careful the HTML is only the menu on the full site you might want to wrap it in another div.
https://jsfiddle.net/452a0fu7/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Festival</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Products</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Tourist Destinations</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Location Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">References</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #47c9af;
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #47c9af;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    color: white;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-top: 3px solid #47c9af;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #47c9af;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @BlackHusky it this is the answer you wanted make sure you upvote and valid the answer with the tick ^^